# forms in virutemart payment option

Tags: forms, joomla

Im not sure if this is possible but I am trying to setup two forms for a payment option for the following website

```
http://103.14.141.156/~wwwbetac/index.php/en/checkout
```

Pretty much over in New Zealand we have a company called Farmlands. We need a simple option under Payment Options or (Select Payment) and it says Farmlands.

From there they can go into a form which just has Farmlands Name and Farmlands Account Number.

Is this at all possible? Sorry if it doesnt make any sense.

Thanks

Comment: cheers for the positive feedback. I thought giving specifics would be easier to explain..

Comment: Let me try again. Yes, it is possible in Joomla to create forms, and you could make those forms handle payments. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am after a payment form so when you click on the option in the shopping cart it gives the user two feilds to type in name and account number and that gets sent along with order request to the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes this can be done as a VM payment plugin.

Longer answer - Payment plugins in VM2.0 are simply Joomla plugins. They do follow specific rules to work as a payment plugin so your best bet (unless you are an experienced programmer) would be to take an existing plugin and make some modifications to match your needs. You didn't mention if Farmlands has an API you will be communicating with or not. If it does, then you will want to start with something like the Authorize.net AIM plugin. If not, then you can use the Offline Payments plugin as your starting point.

Here is the documentation for VM Payment plugins - http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/Payment_plugins

Comment: Hi Brent, Thank you very much for this. No Farmlands doesnt have an API. I pretty much just needed a simple two field form so they can type in their name and account number and click submit. I will have a look for a plugin to edit.